# Supressing type-checking for a particular function in racket that uses eval

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I need to bypass the typechecker for a particular function but have the function's type signature available for type-checking other parts of the program. I think generally `cast` would be used, but that fails here because of variable number of return values.

I'm serializing a set to a string, and then using eval to convert it from a string to set again. Eval evilness aside (I trust source of input), how do I handle this in typed racket?
This is what my implementation is:

```lisp
(: string->set (-> String (Setof Symbol)))
(define (string->set s)
  (eval (read (open-input-string s))))
```

And this is the error that type checker throws at me:

```
Type Checker: type mismatch;
;  mismatch in number of values
;   expected: 1 value
;   given: unknown number
;   in: (eval (read (open-input-string s)))
; [Due to errors, REPL is just module language, requires, and stub definitions]
```

I essentially need to have the typechecker to:

1. Not try to typecheck this method, and
2. Trust the type signature that it returns a set when it's given a string argument, and continue typechecking rest of the code.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here. First, `eval`, returns multiple values while your function returns only one. Second, of the values `eval` returns, it has `Any` type for each value, while your function promises something more specific.

The first problem can be solved with `call-with-values`, which allows you to convert multiple values into just a single value (using `(lambda x x)`).

The second problem can be used with `cast`. It does dynamically check to make sure the type fits, but otherwise lets you dynamically fit a value into a type.

Provided that you know the `eval` statement will only return one value (or you only care about the first value returned), you can use the following code:

```
(: string->set (-> String (Setof Symbol)))
(define (string->set s)
  (define ret
    (first (call-with-values (λ () (eval (read (open-input-string s))))
                             (λ args args))))
  (cast ret (Setof Symbol)))
```

Alternatively you could use use `nocheck` in Typed Racket. I would recommend against doing that though. As it disables all type checking in the entire module.